# Unity Polygon Collider 2D wrong shape

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

My Polygon Collider's shape doesn't fit a simple sprite.
Here's the sprite:
[Track Walls Sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Nyo.png)

That's the collider I get:
[Walls Collider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI6yj.jpg)

I've tried to change sprite mode to Polygon, but that didn't help much.

Comment: Your problem is that your sprite has inline parts that should not be part of the collider, but the collider doesn't know about that. You can build one by hand though.Take a look at this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1020837/polygon-collider-2d-prevent-automatic-generation.html

Comment: That helps, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there are some issues with the transparencies of your sprite, check if there is no blank spaces in the sprite, also I would suggest creating the collider with various box colliders, I've had terrible experiences with generated collider (like mesh collider).

Comment: My sprites will be pretty big later, it will be hard to make box colliders for everything. Thanks for suggestion anyway, I may use it for other cases.